# responsive website with vw and vh, size staying the same size (px) when screen too small

Tags: android, html, css, media-queries, responsive

I made a website completely with vh and vw scaling. Now, for big screens this makes it sufficiently responsive, but now I want to make it responsive for mobile screens. In my website all content is within the middle 60% of the screen. There are shapes, images and text. If I make the screen too small I cannot read the text anymore but there still is 40% of the screen that is almost blank (only a background). Now, when the screen is too narrow, I want the margins left and right (the blank parts of the screen) to get smaller, and the content to not get smaller. Can you do this still using vw and vh or do I have to change everything in pixels?

I tried this already by for example making the body 200vw when the screen was narrower than 500px, but with no luck.

Can anyone help me? It would really suck If I had to make it all over again in pixels as the positions of my elements are all quiet complex.

Thanks!

Comment: Show some code! Learn to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

There are three solutions that came to my mind:

1. Using breakpoints
2. Using min-width & width combination
3. Fluid layout

**1. Breakpoints:**
So, you want to set the width of your main container element to be 60%, if the document width is larger than 768px (for example, max mobile resolution). The code will be:

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto; // horizontally centering element
    background-color: pink; // just to see where the element is
}

// targeting mobile screen size:
@media only screen 
and (max-width: 768px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
}

// targeting larger screens
@media only screen 
and (min-width: 769px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    width: 60vw;
}
```

**2. Min-width:** is maybe an easier solution, but not that good if you also have other elements child elements styled with viewport units, where you just need to determinate what is the minimum `container` width that looks alright and set it as a value of `min-width` property.

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto; // horizontally centering element
    background-color: pink; // just to see where the element is
    width: 60vw;
    min-width: 320px;
}
```

---

Maybe third, the most advanced technique that can help you, if none of above can, is this [Fluid technique](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/fluid-typography/), explained in a detail in this Smashing magazine's post, which is actually the most interesting in typography cases, because the most common technique for the layout is the one that I explained first.

Hope I managed to help.